How do I edit and read a .json file without opening and closing it twice? (python)
I've been wanting to edit the data of a .json file and then read it again with python. I couldn't make this happen in the neat way I wanted it to happen. I had to open the file, write it, then close it and after that, open, read and close it again. My code looks like this:
import json

passed_info = {
    "Tom": 14,
    "Sara": 12,
    "Maureen": 2
}

json_file = open("PathToMy.jsonFile", "r+")
json.dump(passed_info, json_file)

test = json.load(json_file)
print(test)

json_file.close()

If I do it like this, I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PathToMyScript", line 12, in <module>
    test = json.load(json_file)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

I'm  a little new to coding and I dont understand any of this error and I haven't found a satisfying answer yet.
If I open the .json file, write to it, then close it and after that I open it again, read it and close it again, it seems to work:
import json

passed_info = {
    "Tom": 14,
    "Sara": 12,
    "Maureen": 2
}

json_file = open("PathToMy.jsonFile", "r+")
json.dump(passed_info, json_file)

json_file.close()

json_file = open("PathToMy.jsonFile", "r+")
test = json.load(json_file)
print(test)

json_file.close()

Output:
{'Tom': 14, 'Sara': 12, 'Maureen': 2}

Why do I have to close and open my .json file again? Should I just ignore it and move on like the code below or is it bad?

In any file operation, the file object maintains a "current pointer" within the file contents, indicating where the next read and write will occur.  In the first example, when you call json.dump(), this writes the data to the file and the "current pointer" is set to the end of the written data.  So when you call load(), it tries to read from the file at that location, which is at the end of the file, so there is nothing to read!

After you write your JSON data to the file, the current file position is at the very end of the file.  If you read from that position, you get nothing, of course.  You would need to rewind to the beginning of the file - .seek(0) - to be able to read back the data.

The safest way to rewrite a file does involve opening it twice, because it requires writing the content to a completely new file and then doing an atomic rename over the old one; that way there's no point in time when your program or the computer it's on crashing can leave the file corrupt or half-written, which is why major editors follow exactly this practice.

(and if you don't reopen a file after another program did the create-and-rename dance you get the old deleted inode instead of the new one so you can't see the other program's changes, but only see changes made to the inode you got when you first did the open)

The reason you have to reopen the file is because the cursor ends up in the end of the file after the write operation. To avoid having to reopen, go with seek:
import json

passed_info = {
    "Tom": 14,
    "Sara": 12,
    "Maureen": 2
}

with open("PathToMy.jsonFile", "r+") as json_file:
    json.dump(passed_info, json_file) # Write.
    
    json_file.seek(0) # Move cursor to beginning of file.
    
    test = json.load(json_file) # Now read it.

print(test)

